# python print the first line from a loop

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, nmap

I am trying to print the first line from a loop. The loop is generated after parsing an XML file that is being being generated by Nmap. I do not want to use subprocess and call bash commands to do this but I am stumped on how to do it.  It is the second for loop from the code below.

```
from libnmap.parser import NmapParser

rep = NmapParser.parse_fromfile('Linux_int.xml')

for _host in rep.hosts:
    host = ', '.join(_host.hostnames)
    ip = (_host.address)
    print "HostName: ",host,"--", ip
    #print  _host.os_fingerprinted
host_string  = ip


for osmatch in _host.os.osmatches:
    os = osmatch.name
    accuracy = osmatch.accuracy
    print "Operating System Guess: ", os, "Accuracy Detection", accuracy
    #print os.splitlines()[0:1]


for services in _host.services:
    print services.port, services.protocol, services.state, services.service
    server_address = (host_string,services.port)
```

This is the output being generated by the loop.

```
Operating System Guess:  Linux 3.7 - 3.9 Accuracy Detection 98
Operating System Guess:  Linux 3.8 Accuracy Detection 95
Operating System Guess:  AXIS 210A or 211 Network Camera (Linux 2.6) Accuracy Detection 94
Operating System Guess:  Netgear DG834G WAP or Western Digital WD TV media player Accuracy Detection 94
Operating System Guess:  Linux 3.1 Accuracy Detection 93
Operating System Guess:  Linux 3.2 Accuracy Detection 93
Operating System Guess:  Linux 3.7 Accuracy Detection 92
Operating System Guess:  Linux 3.2.0 Accuracy Detection 91
Operating System Guess:  Linux 3.9 Accuracy Detection 91
Operating System Guess:  Linux 2.6.32 - 3.6 Accuracy Detection 91
```

This is the XML file that is being parsed.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7me7mxzawmkqj7m/Linux_int.xml?dl=0

Comment: You shouldn't use `os` as a variable name.  It's a built in.

Comment: Just `break` out of the loop.

Comment: are you looking for the `break` keyword?

Comment: doh.  Thank you folks. The solution is so simple I feel like an airhead now :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, just `break` out of the loop.  If you aren't interested in the other lines at all.

```
for osmatch in _host.os.osmatches:
    os_name = osmatch.name
    accuracy = osmatch.accuracy
    print "Operating System Guess: ", os_name, "Accuracy Detection", accuracy
    break
```

This code could also be simplified like so:

```
print "Operating System Guess: ", \
      _host.os.osmatches[0].name, \
      "Accuracy Detection", _\
      host.os.osmatches[0].accuracy
```

You could put it inside a try/catch block if there is some chance of `_host.os.matches` being empty.

Here is the try/catch in case you get an `IndexError`:

```
try:
    print "Operating System Guess: ", \
          _host.os.osmatches[0].name, \
          "Accuracy Detection", _\
          host.os.osmatches[0].accuracy
except IndexError:
    print "No os matches found."
```

Comment: Yeah. So simple...don't know why I did not think of it. Thank you :)

Comment: Regarding the try catch all. Is this the "exception" or something else? Could you give me a pointer for later reference? A link would do. Would like to learn it.

Comment: In my example, you are accessing the first item in a list, but if that list is completely empty, you'll get an `IndexError`.  With a for loop, this isn't really a consideration, because the for loop just won't do anything if the list happens to be empty.

Answer (score -2):

```
print(_host.os.osmatches[0])
```

Basically will do that without breaking the loop. You don't even have to use a for loop for printing it. It will print first element if it's a list-tuple etc. If it's a string, then it will print first character of it.

Like:

```
a="stackover flow"
print (a[0])
>>>
s
>>>
```

I am surprised that no one wrote this.

Comment: I basically did write that.  One problem is that what you are doing doesn't accomplish exactly the same thing as the poster was trying to do.

Comment: Well, he using for loop and try to print first thing, it is doing that without any loop.

Comment: He's mixing in text, specifically "Operating System Guess: " and "Accuracy Detection" and then only printing specific members of the `osmatches`, whereas you are printing the whole thing.